# Problem about left multiplication of similar matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be two similar $n × n$ matrices, and let $S$ be an invertible matrix testifying this similarity (that is, $A=SBS^{−1}$). Denote by $T_A$ and $T_B$ the linear transformations associated to the matrices $A$ and $B$, respectively (that is, $T_A(x) = Ax$ and $T_B(x) = Bx)$.

(a) Prove that if $x \in \ker(T_B)$ then $Sx \in \ker(T_A)$.

(b) Prove that $\dim\left(\ker(T_A)\right)=\dim\left(\ker(T_B)\right)$ [Hint: show that if $\{ x_1, \ldots , x_n \}$ is a basis of $\ker(T_B)$, then the set $\{ Sx_1, \ldots , Sx_n\}$ is a basis of $\ker(T_A)$].

Can anyone give some insight on how to tackle part(b) of this question?

Comment: "The" invertible matrix with $A=SBS^{-1}$? It is not unique in general.

Comment: @DietrichBurde What do you mean?

Comment: The solution to part b) in the question you linked is incomplete and incorrect. Don't use texts that end with "Does my solution look right?" as a source to learn something.

Comment: Alright. Maybe let me edit the post a little bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key point here is the observation that (as in part (a)), if $x \in \ker(T_B)$ then $Sx \in \ker(T_A)$ and conversely (with similar proof), if $y\in \ker(T_A)$ then $S^{-1}y\in \ker(T_B)$.

Now suppose that $\{ x_1, \ldots , x_n \}$ is a basis for $\ker(T_B)$. We want to show that $\{ Sx_1, \ldots , Sx_n\}$ is a basis for $\ker(T_A)$ (as in the hint) and it will follows that $\dim\left(\ker(T_A)\right)=\dim\left(\ker(T_B)\right)$. So we have to show 2 things:

1/ $\{ Sx_1, \ldots , Sx_n\}$ spans $\ker(T_A)$:

For every $y\in \ker(T_A)$, since $S^{-1}y\in \ker(T_B)$, we have
$$S^{-1}y=b_1x_1+\ldots +b_nx_n$$
Apply $S$ both sides we get $y=b_1Sx_1+\ldots +b_nSx_n$, hence the claim.

2/ $\{ Sx_1, \ldots , Sx_n\}$ is linearly independent:

Suppose that $a_1Sx_1+\ldots +a_nSx_n=0$, by applying $S^{-1}$ we get $a_1x_1+\ldots +a_nx_n=0$, thus, $a_1=\ldots =a_n=0$ since $\{ x_1, \ldots , x_n \}$ is a basis.

Remark: it is clear now that if $\{ y_1,\ldots , y_n\}$ is a basis for $\ker(T_A)$ then $\{ S^{-1}y_1, \ldots ,S^{-1}y_n \}$ is a basis for $\ker(T_B)$.